# getObject returns value of RAM_0_UNIT_PLACEHOLDER for RAM item

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The machine that I am trying to get details for contains the following RAM:

```
2x4GB Kingston 4GB DDR3 1Rx8
```

The RAM item returned for this machine by `getObject` is:

```
{
    'item': {
        'softwareDescriptionId': '',
        'capacity': '8',
        'description': '8 GB RAM',
        'upgradeItemId': '',
        'itemTaxCategoryId': 166,
        'itemCategory': {
            'quantityLimit': 0,
            'sortOrder': 3,
            'categoryCode': 'ram',
            'id': 3,
            'name': 'RAM'
        },
        'keyName': 'RAM_0_UNIT_PLACEHOLDER',
        'units': 'GB',
        'id': 6147
    }
}
```

`RAM_0_UNIT_PLACEHOLDER` does not seem like a valid result and is causing problems when trying to order machines with this configuration. Can someone please confirm if this is the expected behavior or not?

Comment: How are you getting those values? What kind of problems are you getting?  Could you provide the code you are using to order new machines?

Comment: @AlbertCamacho the ordering is now working. I am not sure what changed, but thank you for looking into this.